# Connect Multiple L293D Motor Controllers to Arduino

Tags: arduino, pcb, l293d

I would like to connect 3 L293D Motor controllers to an Arduino Uno with the hopes of powering 6 different dc motors. I was just wondering how to wire this being that one motor controller (which allows for 2 dc motors to be controlled) already takes up most of the pins on the arduino, thanks.

Below is the wiring diagram for how I am hooking up 1 L293D motor controllers to the arduino.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about a [PWM expander](https://core-electronics.com.au/adafruit-12-channel-16-bit-pwm-led-driver-spi-interface-tlc59711.html) like the TLC59711. The link calls it an LED driver but it's just a breakout board for the SPI-PWM expander chip.